# Problems with File IO

Tags: java, file-io

I have to write a program in java that will read a file, search for the words "haystack" and "needle" in each line, and spit out the location of the word "needle" if the word "haystack" is 2 lines before the word "needle". So far my program will read the file and will spit out the location of the 2 words if they are in the line, but I can't figure out how to get it to spit out the location of "needle" if "haystack" is 2 lines before. Also if one of the words is not in the line, it spit out -1 as the location. Can anyone help? (please keep in mind that I am a beginner programmer, and am not very good at it).

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;

public class NeedleInHaystack{

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    int action = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (action != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        System.out.println("Ok, if you don't want to play");;
        System.exit(3);
    }
    String fs = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("User selected: " + fs);
    String fo = fs + "output.txt";
    System.out.println("output: " + fo);

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fs);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fo);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        while (true) {
            String l = br.readLine();
            if (l == null) {
                System.out.println("Looks like we are at the end of the line");
                break;}






            System.out.println("Input: " + l);
            int firstNeedle;
            int firstHaystack;
            firstNeedle = l.indexOf("needle");
            System.out.println("Found needle at:" + firstNeedle);

            firstHaystack = l.lastIndexOf("haystack");
            //String name = l.substring(0, firstNeedle);
            System.out.println("found haystack at: " + firstHaystack);              

            //pw.println(l);
        }
        br.close();
        pw.close();

        System.out.println("That's all, folks!");





    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep a counter / flag to tell you if "haystack" was encountered on a previous line.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a `counter` which will increment in while loop and an integer variable declared outside of loop which will store the line number at which  "haystack" was found.

Now if "haystack" was found 2 lines before "needle", you'll have the line number for "haystack" and you can compare that line number with the `counter`.